# How to restore edx video backup for the edx android app

Tags: android, video, backup, restore, edx

I have installed edx on android and downloaded over 3gb in videos. The app stopped downloading new videos recently so I tried logging in and out and had no luck. I also tried stopping the edx process and restarting but nothing was changed. Then I backed up org.edx.mobile folder which was 3.51 gb and uninstalled the edx app. After that I reinstalled the app and restored the backup. But when I try to play videos on the app it goes straight to download the videos. How can I restore the backup correctly so I can view the downloaded videos in the app. The org.edx.mobile folder contains 2 sub folders for videos and subtitles. The video files have no extension like .mp4 but they can be played on the phone's media player. Sample file name 0b7d6121c6a3b232698274da3754cd57ba3a0953
Many thanks!